# mvn exec:java throws ClassNotFoundException when executed on Jetbrains TeamCity

Tags: java, maven, teamcity

I ran into issue with executing maven exec:java on Jetbrain's TeamCity. The configuration works without any issues locally but on TC it throws constantly:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "…"
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project …: An exception occured while executing the Java class. "…"
```

TC configuration is fairly simple:

- goals: `clean install exec:java`
- additional commandline args: `-DskipTests  -Dexec.mainClass="…" -Dexec.args="…"`

Basically what I'm using locally. However using TC it throws above exception.

I tried explicitly setting current artifact as dependency and configuring compile dependencies as classpath:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>…</groupId>
            <artifactId>…</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But without any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are there any `Caused by` in exception? try to run mvn command on teamcity agent from command line with debug info. maybe you'll see the problem

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `Cuased by`. I'll try to run it from commandline, but we have it dockerised and everything is ad-hoc which makes it a bit more tricky

Comment: The debug output looks ok
```
[13:20:31] :  [Step 1/1] [DEBUG] Collected project classpath [/opt/teamcity/buildAgent/work/dbebb49e09b39be3/target/classes]
[13:20:31] :  [Step 1/1] [DEBUG] Adding to classpath : file:/opt/teamcity/buildAgent/work/dbebb49e09b39be3/target/classes/
…
[13:20:31] :  [Step 1/1] [DEBUG] joining on thread Thread["….SummaryGenerator".main(),5,"….SummaryGenerator"]
[13:20:31]W:  [Step 1/1] [WARNING] 
[13:20:31] :  [Step 1/1] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "….SummaryGenerator"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything boiled down to quotes in `Additional Maven command line parameters:` - TC passes them as parameters so `-Dexec.mainClass="some.package.Class" became`"some.package.Class"`in maven (instead of`some.package.Class`)

I finally noticed it when I was comparing debug from local na remote run:

- remote:

```
[DEBUG] joining on thread Thread["my.package.SummaryGenerator".main(),5,"my.package.SummaryGenerator"]
```

- local:

```
[DEBUG] joining on thread Thread[my.package.SummaryGenerator.main(),5,y.package.SummaryGenerator]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<mainClass>` in the `<configuration>` tag, like this :

```
<configuration>
    <mainClass>com.category.main.Master</mainClass>
    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
</configuration>
```

Then run with the command `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=src.com.category.main.Master`

Comment: Tried it already, however it didn't work. And if I would want to have multiple classes then I'd have to play with executions (which are tied to particular phases)